# Using find and du, to display folder size

Tags: bash, shell

I have a repository which we need to monitor and keep track of its usage.
 We have a rule where older files are purged regularly.
 find command is used to identify the older files
 find /srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/ -name '*nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f

The above command is used with rm to delete files.

Lets assume the output of the find command is this:

```
 /srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-nuget-test/Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller/1.0.0/Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller-1.0.0.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-nuget-test/Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller/1.0.1/Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller-1.0.1.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-nuget-test/MSBuild.ILMerge.Task/1.0.5/MSBuild.ILMerge.Task-1.0.5.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-nuget-test/Microsoft.Bcl/1.1.10/Microsoft.Bcl-1.1.10.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-nuget-test/NuGet.CommandLine/3.3.0/NuGet.CommandLine-3.3.0.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-nuget-test/NuGet.CommandLine/3.4.3/NuGet.CommandLine-3.4.3.nupkg
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-nuget-  test/NuGet.CommandLine/2.8.5/NuGet.CommandLine-2.8.5.nupkg
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-nuget-test/NuGet.CommandLine/2.8.3/NuGet.CommandLine-2.8.3.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/mynexus-nuget-releases/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/2.0.3/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-2.0.3.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/myNexus-nuget-releases/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/2.0.0/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-2.0.0.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/mynexus-nuget-releases/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/1.2.0/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-1.2.0.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/mynexus-nuget-releases/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/1.0.2/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-1.0.2.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/mynexus-nuget-releases/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/1.0.0/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-1.0.0.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/mynexus-nuget-releases/.nexus/attributes/MyTest.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/2.0.3/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-2.0.3.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/mynexus-nuget-releases/.nexus/attributes/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/2.0.0/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-2.0.0.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/mynexus-nuget-releases/.nexus/attributes/MyTest.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/1.2.0/MyTest.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-1.2.0.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/mynexus-nuget-releases/.nexus/attributes/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App/1.0.2/Testing.TestNugetNamingConvention.App-1.0.2.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-testing/.nexus/attributes/.nexus/trash/Akka/1.1.1/Akka-1.1.1.nupkg   
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-testing/.nexus/attributes/Akka/1.1.1/Akka-1.1.1.nupkg  
/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/nish-testing/Akka/1.1.1/Akka-1.1.1.nupkg
```

My question is this, i want to display the ammount of diskspace that i can save before the actual remove,
 i.e. lets say the above *.nupkg files are old and needs to be deleted, hence the user should have a stats as how much space will be actually saved

I need the output something like this

```
xxx MB /nish-nuget-test  
yyy GB /mynexus-nuget-releases  
zzz KB /nish-testing
```

I need only one level depth `@/srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage`, and all the sum of file and folder should be recursively added up

The closest i could get is this

```
find /srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/ -name '*nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -print0 | xargs --null -I '{}' du -sh '{}' | sort -h
```

However this just lists out the individual files, i tried to add --max-depth=1, but couldn't get the syntax correct.

Alternatively i used, `find /srv/nexus/nexus-data/storage/ -name '*nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -exec du -ch {} + | grep total$`
but this just lists out the sum of the entire file list

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a proposal in two steps.

**Step 1**, get the `find` that works for you and identify the columns that you are going to need. Try with:

```
cd /srv/nexus-data/storage
find . -name '*.nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

I prefer to `cd` to the directory you want and avoid all the subdirectories that you are not interested in.

**Step 2**. Given the output to that, locate the columns that contain the size of the file (in my case, #5) and the name of the file (in my case #9). Then, run the `find` through the following:

```
find . -name '*.nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '
{
  split($9, a, "/");
  sum[a[2]] += $5;
}

END {
  for (i in sum) {
    print i, sum[i];
  }
}
'
```

If necessary, change `$5` and `$9` with the columns for the size and the file name, respectively (`awk` will count *columns* around white space, `$1` being the first and so on.) `awk` will process all the files, splitting the name around the character `/` so that array `a` has the result and `a[2]` the *first* subdirectory that you want summed. The `END` bit will output the accumulated sums along with the subdirectories they belong to.

The `awk` script may be turned into a one-liner, but I leave it in its expanded form for clariry.

**EDIT**: Using @CharlesDuffy excellent suggestion and assuming you have GNU find (and no filenames with newlines in them), you could use:

```
find . -name '*.nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -printf '%s\t%h\n' | awk '
{
  split($2, a, "/");
  sum[a[2]] += $1;
}

END {
  for (i in sum) {
    print i, sum[i];
  }
}
'
```

Finally, just for the sake of completeness, this one can do with newlines too:

```
find . -name '*.nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -printf '%s\t%h\0' | awk '
BEGIN {
  RS="\0";
}

{
  split($2, a, "/");
  sum[a[2]] += $1;
}

END {
  for (i in sum) {
    print i, sum[i];
  }
}
'
```

Comment: Parsing output of `ls -l` [is not good practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (see the section "Getting Metadata On A File" for your immediate use case). If using GNU `find`, in particular, `-printf` can be used with a format string that prints file size directly.

Comment: `find ... -printf '%s\t%h\0'`, for instance, will print size in bytes for each matched file, a tab, then the directory name, and then a NUL. This lets you unambiguously read even directory names that contain newlines.

Comment: Can we have the size displayed in Kb, GB, MB

Comment: Yes, replace `print i, sum[i];` by `printf "%s %.1fKb\n", i, sum[i]/1024;` for Kb with 1 decimal, by `printf "%s %.1fMb\n", i, sum[i]/1024/1024;` for Mb, and so on.

Comment: I have a followup Q; cd /srv/nexus-data/storage; find . -name '*.nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -printf '%s\t%h\n',     the above commands will work for any directory under /storage; however if i need it to display only nuget*snapshots type of directory, it dosent work as intended, If i modify the find command as   find nuget*snapshots -name '*.nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -printf '%s\t%h\n'; the out put is for the child folders under nuget*snapshots, where as i need the output for nuget*snapshots only.  Hope i make my q clear

Comment: The line `sum[a[2]] += $1;` is using the first subdirectory name after `/` to do the counting. You may change `a[2]` to something else or change the initial `cd /srv/nexus-data/storage` for a different behavior.

Comment: Hi Javier,I want to put in a regular expression, i need to dispay this sum of files and sub directories for nuget'*'snapshots only,; however if i put in the same wildcard in the a[2], i get output for all subdirectories too

Comment: this works for me find ./rna`*`snapshots -name '*.nupkg' -mtime +175 -type f -printf "%s\t%h\n"

Comment: Glad to hear that.